# Centering an item without expanding the overall size of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a 100dayscss.com clone page for practice purposes.
I'm trying to do it in my own fashion, peaking at the source code every now and then. I've got this  **lovely**  code that does not cooperate with me very well.

My main problem is: I'd like to center the `.box` item, but it just keeps being "off" and expanding the size of the page. How do I make it work so it just gets in the middle of it, right below the first container?

I would like to keep an even margin between the sides of the page, and a slight margin in between the 2 boxes.

Is there a convenient way to center such items, relatively to the size of the page?
I also tried to set the `.container2`'s `position` to `relative`, but it doesn't appear relative to the first `.container`, and messes everything up.

It comes with another questions:

How do I make the page horizontally static? We all know how inconvenient it is to operate on this axis, and I really don't want to have that horizontal scroll-bar  *ever.* What mistakes should I avoid?

Here's the code, perhaps someone could help me out. :) Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-style: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.item {
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;  
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: #51aaa3;
    
}
    
.item-1 {
    flex-grow: 1.5;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 4
    }
.item-2 {
    flex-grow: 2;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1
}
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 40%;;
    height: 1200px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: -600px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: none;
    
}

.container2 {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 24px 32px;
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    z-index: 20;
}

.box {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 24px 32px;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg"></div> 
        <div class="item item-1"></div>
        <div class="item item-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <iframe class="box" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fJ9rUzIMcZQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add `padding:center` to the `.box`item and try to make the first container to float up